# Php routing displaying two pages for one url

Tags: php, html, http, routes

I found little router like this

```
class Router
 {
     private static $routes = array();

     private function __construct() {}
     private function __clone() {}

     public static function route($pattern, $callback)
     {

         $pattern = '/^' . str_replace('/', '\/', $pattern) . '$/';
         self::$routes[$pattern] = $callback;
     }

     public static function execute($url)
     {

         foreach (self::$routes as $pattern => $callback)
         {
             if (preg_match($pattern, $url, $params))
             {
                 
                 array_shift($params);
                 return call_user_func_array($callback, array_values($params));

             }
         }

     }
 }
```

and added some routes to my header.php

```
//config
  require_once 'classes/router.php';
  Router::route('/', function(){
    require_once 'index.php';
  });

  Router::route('/about', function(){
    require_once 'about.php';
  });
```

and when i using href to about page

```
<a href="about" class="text-success text-primary" target="_blank">About Us</a>
```

I get html document containing two pages what is not that i want to see

1. page for about.php (require header, content of about page, require footer)
2. page for index.php (require header, content of index page, require footer)

I was trying to use another router, but Im getting the same result.

Any comments will be appreciated. Thanks everyone in advance)

P.s It is very hard to understand the question, so here is the image.
The black line is a footer, and page should end with this, but instead, the index.php is printed under the footer.[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gqopw.jpg)

Comment: If i understand right,  you need to navigate to about page, but not to open another tab? If so , just remove `target="_blank"`. This will change the route, but do not open second tab.

Comment: No, it like writes two html documents to one tab